# sqlalchemy.exc.NoSuchColumnError when I'm querying in parent process

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

I'm processing large data from severity sources so I use mutiprocessing. My process works with Python 3.5.2, SQLAlchemy (1.1.9) and PyMySQL (0.7.11).

The process starts when I run from command line:

```
$ python3 input_process.py
```

But I get the exception:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.NoSuchColumnError: "Could not locate column in row for column 'fp_feed_types.id'"
```

Below is my code:

**input_process.py**

```
from feed_process.main_process import run

if __name__ == "__main__":
    run()
```

**feed_process/main_process.py**

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
from feed_process.models import FeedIn
from feed_process.models.db import DBSession    

def process_feed(feed_id):
    session = DBSession()    
    feed_in = session.query(FeedIn).get(feed_id)
    print(feed_in.feed_type)

def run(urls = None, feed_ids = None, num_workers = None):
    DBSession().query(FeedId).get(26)

    feed_ids = [1, 2, 3]

    with Pool(processes = num_workers) as pool:
        responses = [pool.apply_async(process_feed, (feed_id,)) for feed_id in feed_ids]

        for response in responses:
            response.get()
```

**feed_process/models/db.py**

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, sessionmaker

connection_string = ""

engine = create_engine(connection_string)
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
DBSession = scoped_session(Session)
```

**feed_process/models/model.py**

```
Base = declarative_base()

class FeedType(Base):
    __tablename__ = "fp_feed_types"

    id = Column(String, primary_key = True)

class FeedIn(Base):
    __tablename__ = "fp_feeds_in"

    id = Column("feedid", Integer, primary_key = True)
    name  = Column("feedname", String)

    feed_type_id = Column(String, ForeignKey("fp_feed_types.id"))
    feed_type = relationship("FeedType")
```

If I delete the line `DBSession().query(FeedId).get(26)` in `run` function The process works great :|. Note that 26 is a random number.

And yes, column 'fp_feed_types.id' exists.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Not related to your error, but be careful with SQLAlchemy and multiprocessing, if on a system that supports forking. It'll possibly end up sharing DB connections between processes through the engine's connection pooling, which is bad, if it ends up finalizing said connections in another process while other is still using them. See http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/pooling.html#using-connection-pools-with-multiprocessing

Comment: Thank you. I will try add line eng.dispose but I don't understand it suppose that scoped_session function avoids share the same Session in fork process

Comment: A scoped session provides **thread** local sessions. It does not help you with multiprocessing, but instead may complicate things, since threads and forking may be a recipe for trouble.